# Seaborn KDE is not giving a graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to do KDE estimation for a data set but it is showing an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv("node1.txt", header = None) 
sns.kdeplot(df[0]);
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

nodes1.txt has each element of type float64

[image]

I have no idea what is going wrong. I saw a video on youtube and this is exactly as shown in it but I am getting the error when I try to do it in Spyder. If I use a jupyter notebook, it just keeps on running and doesn't give me any graph. If I do not use the semi colon in the 4th line of my code, I do not get a graph, I just get `<AxesSubplot:xlabel='0', ylabel='Density'>` as output. And the kernel dies after a minute of running this code.

Please help me out

Comment: You might be running an old seaborn version. Did you try `sns.kdeplot(x=df[0].values)`?

Comment: You can also upgrade seaborn on your computer:  `pip install seaborn --upgrade`

Comment: @Pedro Yes I will update it now
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Numpy library installed seems to have an error. Once it has been rectified the list not callable error should be solved.
To recity the library, update your Anaconda by running the below code in a terminal

```
conda update conda
```

Seaborn also needs to be updated as you are running an older version.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you post a question here, you should always try to include a MRE (Minimum Reproducible Example), in your case recreate a Dataframe from your `"node1.txt"` like I did with a `random` vector. Specifying the software versions is also helpfull. Here it is with Python 3.7.4, Spyder 3.3.6, Pandas 0.25.1 and Seaborn 0.11.2.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random

a=[]
for i in range(269):
    a.append(random.uniform(-8, 8))

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Check `print(df)` and `print(df[0])`:

```
print(df)
            0
0   -7.777958
1   -1.298064
2    2.326718
3   -6.880657
4    4.813914
..        ...
264 -3.309862
265  5.009295
266  4.010151
267  1.665604
268 -0.209954

[269 rows x 1 columns]

print(df[0])
0     -7.777958
1     -1.298064
2      2.326718
3     -6.880657
4      4.813914
  
264   -3.309862
265    5.009295
266    4.010151
267    1.665604
268   -0.209954
Name: 0, Length: 269, dtype: float64
```

Now, plot the KDE:

```
In[1]: sns.kdeplot(df[0])
Out[1]: <AxesSubplot:xlabel='0', ylabel='Density'>
```

[image]

If you do not get this output with this code, try restarting the kernel and/or open a new IPython console and try again (with this code first, because it is reproducible). If you're still not able to get this output, try to update/upgrade your seaborn package: `pip install seaborn --upgrade`

Comment: The 4 lines of code I provided is all the code I have written. What you have done is write the same code as mine except in you are not getting an error and you even get a graph as output. I am getting a type error saying list is not callable. When I run it on jupyter, I do not get a type error but I never get the graph either

Comment: If you have you tried my code and did not get the same as my output, try restarting the kernel and/or open a new IPython console, and try again, first with my code (that is reproducible) and if successful then with yours.

Comment: The numpy in my PC had some errors which I corrected by updating conda. Jupyter has always been buggy for me. Thank you so much !